# What does a function return when a vector is divided by a scalar as last operation?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to make sense of [this script](https://www.tradingview.com/script/Ey4q9m1t-Rescaled-Range/) which implements a overbought/ oversold range. Lacking a deep understanding of the internals, I am struggling to make sense of the following code segment:

```
// Function to convert a price series into a return series.  That is, every
// periods data point is the return from the previous period.  For example, if the value
// at period[n] = $550 and at period[n-1] = $500, then the return for period[n] = 1.10 
// (550/500).
convert_to_return(src) =>
    src / src[1]

security_close = security(syminfo.tickerid, resolution, close)
return_series = convert_to_return(security_close)
```

If I understand it correctly, `security_close` is a vector of close-prices for several trading periods. `return_series` then takes this vector as an argument and divides the vector by the element at position 1, which, since arrays are 0-based, refers to the second newest element in the passed series.

Does `convert_to_return` then return the whole vector or just the scalar `src[0]/src[1]`? I am assuming it returns a vector, but then the purpose of that function does not make much sense to me, as to why one would want to rescale a series to it's second element.

Comment: What is your actual question? Clearly (as the name indicates) `return_series = convert_to_return(...)` returns a vector. Everything in PS returns vectors.

Comment: @not2qubit then what does the function actually compute? how is dividing the vector by the second element creating a series where each element is divided by its predecessor?

Comment: @not2qubit Is `src` a shorthand for `src[0]`?

Comment: As can be seen from [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Type_system.html#series) and [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-referencing-operator), you find that diving a series by a scalar, return a series with each item divided. The notion of `[]` is called the *history operator*. So `src[0]` would be the current (last) value in the *src* vector.